# Where is the slider transition time?

Tags: html, css

I've inherited code (not really a UI guy) and I am trying to find out where the time to set to show the next slide.  I am not using the Carousel fyi. I thought there might be a transition in the CSS code, but there isn't. I am just trying to change the time for the users to see what delay they would like.

Here is the code:

```css
/* Slider */
.da-left {
    margin-top: -35px;
}
.slider-top {
    background: linear-gradient(110deg, rgba(1,1,1,.35) 0%, rgba(1,1,1,.35) 85%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 85.03%);
    margin-top: 70px;
    height: 130px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #cecbe6;
    display: block;
    width: 458pt;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    line-height: 130px;
}
.slider-diagonal-line {
    width: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cecbe6;
    position: relative;
    left: -25px;
    top: -10px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(28px) rotate(110deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(28px) rotate(110deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(28px) rotate(110deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(28px) rotate(110deg);
    transform: translateY(28px) rotate(110deg);
}
.slider-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.slider-icon img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 55px;
}
.slider-description {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
.slider-square {
    background: rgba(1, 1, 1, .35);
    width: 50px;
    height: 79pt;
    display: table-cell;
}
.slider-bottom {
    background: linear-gradient(110deg, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 85%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 85.2%);
    height: 81px;
    padding: 15px 70px 15px 15px;
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 18pt;
    line-height: 27px;
    letter-spacing: -0.52px;
    max-width: 450px;
}
.da-img img {
    max-width: 65%;
    max-height: 80%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="da-slider" data-interval="1000" class="da-slider d-none d-sm-block" style="background-image: url(&quot;Content/Images/Slider/Backgrounds/CapeHatterasLighthouse.jpg&quot;); background-position: 50% 0%;">
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlSlider" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CONSTR %>' SelectCommand="spQuerySlider" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
   <asp:Repeater ID="SliderRepeater" DataSourceID="SqlSlider" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <div class="da-slide" style="<%# Eval("Visible")%>">
         <a href="<%# Eval("URL") %>">
           <div class="da-left">
             <div class="slider-top"><%# Eval("Title") %> </div>
             <div class="slider-square"></div>
             <div class="slider-bottom">
               <div class="slider-description"><%# Eval("Text") %> </div>
               <div class="slider-diagonal-line"></div>
               <div class="slider-icon">
                 <img src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StyleHubBaseUrl"]%>assets/img/Slider Icons/
                                    <%# Eval("IconFileName") %>" />
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </a>
         <div class="da-img">
           <a href="<%# Eval("URL") %>">
             <img src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StyleHubBaseUrl"]%>assets/img/Slider Images/
                                <%# Eval("ImageFileName") %>" />
           </a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
   <div class="da-arrows">
     <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
     <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I would first look into figuring out what slider/carousel plugin you are using. There is more to this and I'm going to assume its in javascript that you are missing.

Comment: Timing will be controlled in Javascript. You've only shown us HTML and CSS.

Comment: That was it.  I found the js code and the interval.  Thanks!